# Javascript behaving weirdly

Tags: javascript, jquery

the following function does not work as I thought it should have. For some reason, the loop breaks whenever one the the validate function returns false. Why is that?

Here is my code :

```
function validateGroup(input) {
    if (!input.value.match(/^[0-9]{0,2}$/)) {
        $(input).addClass("invalidField");
        return false;
    }
    $(input).removeClass("invalidField");
    return true;
}

function validateClass(input) {
    if (!input.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,9}$/)) {
        $(input).addClass("invalidField");
        return false;
    }
    $(input).removeClass("invalidField");
    return true;    
}

function validateData() {
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

    var valid = true;

    for (var i = 0, arrayLength = rows.length; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
        valid = valid && validateClass(rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0]);
        valid = valid && validateGroup(rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[1]);
        valid = valid && validateGroup(rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[2]);     
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks"? When one of validation function return `false`, the answer will be `false`, as you're doing only `&&` operations on it.

Comment: Which function breaks and which function returns false?

Comment: use firebug and step through it

Comment: Do you have any kind of javascript error? (Firebug or safari's development menu would show that).

Comment: I know it will remain false, but the thing is, the other validate functions never get called...

Comment: You know you could jQuery to much greater effect in your validateData() function...

Comment: No javascript error, when I do step by step, it just skip right to the end of the function i becomes equal to arrayLenght

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the statement valid && validateClass(...) will not call the validateClass method if valid is false.  I think what you want to do is change the order of those to

```
valid = validateClass(rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0]) && valid;
valid = validateGroup(rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[1]) && valid;
valid = validateGroup(rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[2]) && valid;
```

Javascript doesn't bother evaluating the rest of an && expression if it already knows that the result is false.

Comment: I know how the && operator works but somehow I didn't think about this at all!

Comment: Aaarg, using side effects in shortcircuited operations. Everyone knows you shouldn't do that and still it happens :) Great observation!

Comment: Nice... I didn't even think of that! +1

Comment: using side effects in short-circuited operations is often desirable, especially in the case of checking if something is null and if it isn't, doing something to it.  It's just that it backfired in this particular case...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to run the validate functions on each iteration even if ‘valid’ was already set to false. However the && operation you are using will short-circuit, so although the loop will continue the validate functions will not be called on subsequent iterations.

A really simple alternative which would work the way you want would be:

```
for (var i = 0, arrayLength = rows.length; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
   if(!validateClass(rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0]))  valid = false;
   if(!validateGroup(rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[1]))  valid = false;
   if(!vvalidateGroup(rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[2])) valid = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that is the intent of the function. The three lines of

```
valid = valid && validate...
```

mean that if any of the validate functions ever hits false `valid` will remain false for the rest of the loop.

Comment: Of course, I want valid to remain false, but the rest of the validate functions never get called even though I still want them to!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the **lazy evaluation** scheme Javascript uses with `&&`. Try a single `&` instead.

[Short-circuit evaluation: Support in common programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation#Support_in_common_programming_languages)

Answer (score 0):

It's called short-circuiting. Quick fix: replace each line with

```
valid = validateClass(rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0]) && valid;
```